# Autocomplete dropdown with checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to implement auto complete drop-down with check-boxes, in asp.net. Can someone assist me on this?

Comment: For sure somebody can do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin [dropdown-check-list](https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/).
It is a javascript plugin based on the jQuery library that transforms a regular select html element into a dropdown checkbox

I think this will help you to complete first phase of your task.